# Working with webform delphi xe7 fmx

Tags: android, delphi, oauth, webforms, firemonkey

I'm using webform from Rest.Authenticator.OAuth.Webform.Fmx to get access to one of the google api. This mechanism is working on my desktop app, so I want to use it on android app. But there is a trouble: I can't copy access code, from Twebbrowser on webform. Android does not raise mechanism of copying text.

What is the right way to solve this problem?
 Parse page from webbrowser?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the solution, the token i need will be here:

```
webform.lasttitle
```

After changing this title I will copy it and close webform automatically.